# .NET MAUI Using full camera resolution

Tags: c#, ios, .net, visual-studio, maui

Does anybody know how to use the full resolution of the iPhone's camera when taking photos and/or videos in a .NET MAUI app. Below is the code im using to take a video and then save that file to the filesystem. But the after reviewing the video it is definetly not even close to the full quality that the camera offers. It also displays very low resolution in the viewport.

```
FileResult video = await MediaPicker.Default.CaptureVideoAsync();
if (video != null)
{
    // save the file into local storage
    string localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, video.FileName);

    using Stream sourceStream = await video.OpenReadAsync();

    using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

    await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);
}
```

Comment: It doesn’t look like MediaPicker exposes any options to set quality or resolution.  You will probably have to use the native platform APIs to set higher quality capture settings.